# Using Regex on TextBox With Any Date Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm hoping to accomplish this but accepting any format: 01/01/2001 or 01-01-2001 or 01-01-2001. Any ideas?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack = "true" CausesValidation = "true">     </asp:TextBox>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate = "TextBox1"
ValidationExpression = "^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$"// anyway i can add or here with other regex requirements
runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date format. Valid Date Format see above">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Comment: What format do you want the date to be in? Are you wanting to accept any date format or just a specific format?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateTime.TryParse` to validate the `DateTime` with a `CustomValidator`:

```
protected void ValidateDate(Object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{ 
    string[] allowedFormats = { "dd/MM/yyyy","dd-MM-yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy" };
    DateTime dt;
    e.IsValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(e.Value, allowedFormats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
}
```

aspx:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="ValidDate" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" OnServerValidate="ValidateDate" runat="server"></asp:CustomValidator>
```